# Copy formula replacing the references in their arguments by values

Tags: google-sheets

Is there an easy way to copy range referenced formulas with values.
In particular example I have column `A` with a list of URLs, column `B` with a list of names, I combine them in column `C` formulas:
`=HYPERLINK(A1;B1)`

And then I would like to copy all column `C` cells but with already modified formulas, where references are replaced with actual values, like:
`=HYPERLINK("http://w3c.org";"W3C")`

I need to have this to let other users easily copy formulas to other sheets.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, although not exactly by copying the formulas you already have. You need a "meta-formula" that makes that formula:

```
="=HYPERLINK(""" & A1 & """;""" & B1 & """)"
```

If A1 is "google.com" and B1 is "Google", the above evaluates to text

```
=HYPERLINK("google.com";"Google")
```

which is the formula you need (the doubling of " marks is necessary to escape them within a string). So far this is still text, though. Next steps:

1. Copy the column of meta-formulas
2. Paste them to a new column **as values** (Ctrl-Shift-V or its analog)
3. Format the new column as "automatic" even if it already is formatted that way: select it, go to Format -> Number -> Automatic.

Now your new column has the formulas you want.